# Symfony2-Cropit | How to get back my cropped image?

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, plugins, crop

i'm very disapointed with this plugin.I'm a noob in JS/Jquery but i very need this plugin for my site...
So i found cropit here : http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/

I don't know how to get back my cropped image in my controller and save it...
So my form is :

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.image, 'Image', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}})}}
      <div class="image-cropper">
           <!-- This is where the preview image is displayed -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
              <div class="cropit-image-preview-container">
               <div class="cropit-image-preview"></div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div> 
                <!-- This range input controls zoom -->
                    <!-- You can add additional elements here, e.g. the image icons -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
              <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input" />
            </div>
          </div>
              {{ form_errors(form.image) }}

          <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              {{ form_widget(form.image) }}
                <div class="select-image-btn">Select new image</div>
                <div class="send_image">Get Cropped image.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

my Jquery code :

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/cropit-master/dist/jquery.cropit.js') }}"></script>

<script>
 $(function () {
     $('.select-image-btn').click(function(){
         $('.cropit-image-input').click();
    });


      var z = $('.image-cropper');
      z.cropit({
          exportZoom: 0.5,
          imageBackground: true,
          imageBackgroundBorderWidth: 15
      });
      $('.send_image').click(function() {
            var h =z.cropit('export');
            alert(h);
       });
   });
</script>
```

my Image.php entity :

```
     public function getFile()
  {
    return $this->file;
  }

  public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
  {
    $decoded = urldecode($file);
    $exp = explode(';', $decoded);
    $exp = explode(':', $exp[0]);
    $data = array_pop($exp);
    $this->file = imagecreatefromstring($file);


    if (null !== $this->url) {
      $this->tempFilename = $this->url;

      $this->url = null;
      $this->alt = null;
    }
  }

  /**
   * @ORM\PrePersist()
   * @ORM\PreUpdate()
   */
  public function preUpload()
  {

    if (null === $this->file) {
      return;
    }


    $this->url = $this->file->guessExtension();


    $this->alt = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
 }

  /**
   * @ORM\PostPersist()
   * @ORM\PostUpdate()
   */
  public function upload()
  {

    if (null === $this->file) {
      return;
    }


    if (null !== $this->tempFilename) {
      $oldFile = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->tempFilename;
      if (file_exists($oldFile)) {
        unlink($oldFile);
      }
    }


    $this->file->move(
      $this->getUploadRootDir(), // Le répertoire de destination
      $this->id.'.'.$this->url   // Le nom du fichier à créer, ici « id.extension »
    );
  }

  /**
   * @ORM\PreRemove()
   */
  public function preRemoveUpload()
  {
    $this->tempFilename = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->url;
  }

  /**
   * @ORM\PostRemove()
   */
  public function removeUpload()
  {
    if (file_exists($this->tempFilename)) {
      // On supprime le fichier
      unlink($this->tempFilename);
    }
  }

  public function getUploadDir()
  {
    // On retourne le chemin relatif vers l'image pour un navigateur
    return 'uploads/img';
  }

  protected function getUploadRootDir()
  {
    // On retourne le chemin relatif vers l'image pour notre code PHP
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
  }

  public function getWebPath()
  {
    return $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getId().'.'.$this->getUrl();
  }
```

I saw lots of posts but nothing is working for me and i don't very understand.
So somebody can help and explain to me please?
thank you

EDITED : MY FIRST METHOD

my form was with an hidden input to save the base64 data :

```
 $('form').submit(function() {
        // Move cropped image data to hidden input
        var imageData = $('.image-cropper').cropit('export');
        $('.hidden-image-data').val(imageData);
      };``
```

and my Imagetype with a file input to load the original image and hidden input to save the base64 image.

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', 'file', array(
                'attr' => array('class' => 'cropit-image-input')))
            ->add('file', 'hidden', array('attr' => array('class' => 'hidden-image-data')))

        ;
    }
```

my controller was still the same.

Comment: the thing is that with any of this js cropper scripts you will not get `UploadedFile` object in your setFile field. i used model data transformer and custom field type to make it work with symfony.

Comment: I know that i get back à base64 image no? Can u show me how you do that please?

Comment: yes. you will get base64 with some irrelevant prefix. the idea is to use `hidden` field and DataTransformer to transform it in form of file. Sorry, i'm not sure i can share the source.

Comment: @Flushdrew, Could you check my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved.

In addition using [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle)

@K-Phoen response has been of great use to direct the solution. [VichUploaderBundle & Cropit - Pass base64 to a File instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31496559/5763965)

this is my code:

**User.php**, this and more VichUploaderBundle setup [look here](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md)

```
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;

//...
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * User
 *
 * ........
 * ........
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 * ........
 * ........
 * 
 */
class User extends BaseUser {

    /**
     * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
     * 
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="user_avatar", fileNameProperty="avatarName")
     * 
     * @var File
     */
    private $avatar;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $avatarName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    //....


    /**
     * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
     * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the  update. If this
     * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
     * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
     * during Doctrine hydration.
     *
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
     */
    public function setAvatar(File $image = null) {
        $this->avatar= $image;

        if ($image) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return File
     */
    public function getAvatar() {
        return $this->avatar;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $avatarName
     */
    public function setAvatarName($avatarName) {
        $this->avatarName= $avatarName;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAvatarName() {
        return $this->avatarName;
    }

}
```

**UserType.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

//...
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer\ImageStringToFileTransformer;

class UserType extends AbstractType {

    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder                
            ->add('avatar', 'hidden', [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'hidden-image-data'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('imagedata', 'file', [
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'cropit-image-input'
                ]
            ])
            //...
            ;

        $builder->get('avatar')
            ->addModelTransformer(new ImageStringToFileTransformer($this->manager));
    }

    //...

}
```

**ImageStringToFileTransformer.php**, here the magic is done, we convert base64 string to UploadedFile

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * Description of ImageStringToFileTransformer
 *
 * @author Juanjo García
 */
class ImageStringToFileTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface {

    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager) {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a string (base64) to an object (File).
     *
     * @param  string $imageString
     * @return File|null
     * @throws TransformationFailedException if no object (File)
     */
    public function reverseTransform($imageString) {

        // no base64? It's optional, so that's ok       
        if (!$imageString) {
            return;
        }

        preg_match('/data:([^;]*);base64,(.*)/', $imageString, $matches);

        $mimeType = $matches[1];
        $imagenDecodificada = base64_decode($matches[2]);
        $filePath = sys_get_temp_dir() . "/" . uniqid() . '.png';
        file_put_contents($filePath, $imagenDecodificada);

        $file = new UploadedFile($filePath, "user.png", $mimeType, null, null, true);

        if (null === $file) {
            // causes a validation error
            // this message is not shown to the user
            // see the invalid_message option
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                 'An issue with number "%s" does not exist!', $imageString
            ));
        }

        return $file;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms an object (File) to a string (base64).
     *
     * @param  File|null $file
     * @return string
     */
    public function transform($file) {
        return '';
    }

}
```

**services.yml**

```
services:

    # datatransformer before saving to image
    app.form.type.user:
        class: AppBundle\Form\UserType
        arguments: 
            entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        tags:
            - 
                name: form.type
```

in my Twig, 
**my_form.html.twig**

```
<script src="{{ asset('jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('jquery.cropit.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('jquery.custom.js') }}"></script>

{% form_theme form with ['AppBundle:Forms:vich_cropit_fields.html.twig'] %}

{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('the_path'), 'method': 'POST', 'multipart': true, 'attr': {'class': 'the_class', 'role': 'form'} }) }}
    <div class="image-editor">
        <div class="cropit-image-preview-container">
            <div class="cropit-image-preview"></div>
        </div>
        {{ form_widget(form.avatar) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.imagedata) }} 
        <div class="image-size-label">
        Resize image
        </div>
        <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
        {% if app.user.avatarName %}
            <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(app.user, 'avatar') }}" id="current-avatar" class="hide" />
        {% endif %}
    </div>   

    {{ form_rest(form) }}       

    <button type="submit" name="submit">Save</button>  

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

init Cropit, **jquery.custom.js**

```
(function ($) {

    $('.image-editor').cropit({
          exportZoom: 0.5,
          imageBackground: true,
          imageBackgroundBorderWidth: 50
      });

    $('.image-editor').cropit('imageSrc', $("#current-avatar").attr('src'));

    $('form').submit(function () {
        // Move cropped image data to hidden input
        var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export');
        $('.hidden-image-data').val(imageData);
    });

}).apply(this, [jQuery]);
```

since I have not found an answer to the solution anywhere, I decided to leave here, for everyone who needs it. I hope you find it helps.

Comment: Oh i haven't seen this answer ! I will try it in my code. Thank you for tout time and explaination !

Comment: Hi @jjgarcía i need your help please i try to use your solution in one of my project. but unsuccessfully it doesn't work. I can resize the image and upload it but database table field that witch saved image path is empty after entity saved. And i work on since and about 4 months. i'm tired please help me. sorry if i have some mistakes, English is not my main language.

Comment: Hi @angel did you include this line  * @Vich\Uploadable in your Entity definition? did you get any error?

Comment: @jjgarcía Yes i already done this but didn't work. I I've the same error. maybe i should post my source code for you help me

Comment: @angel Ok, create a Gist with you code, And I try to make a way to check it out.

Answer (score -1):

to get the path of the saved file:

```
<?php
public function getUploadedFilePath()
{
    return $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->tempFilename;
}
```

try to get image data like on copit page:

```
<script>
var h = $imageCropper.cropit('export', {
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  quality: .9,
  originalSize: true
});
</script>
```

Comment: But my cropped image is not saved for now.My code just save the original image.That's my big problem.

Comment: I don't understand cuz iwhen i click on my "select image" div or "get cropped image" div to get the base64 data nothing happened... is there any bug in my code?

Comment: I edited my Jquery and form in my question.So now the "select new image is working but not the "get cropped image" on my website. I tryed it on JsFiddle and it works so there's maybe a conflict in my script.What could be the problem? I use bootstrap and a template for bootstrap named clean-blog.

Comment: how do you send the image to the server? do you send the crop informations and have to crop the image again (for example with imagemagick) in php or do you send the base64 informations? please with code example.

Comment: I edited with some code at the end of my first question.thank you

Comment: No...i gived up this and try an other method